# How can I color a part of a letter in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, typography, typefaces

I'm trying to color the arms of a capital T in Georgia font on Illustrator for a project, but I can't do it. Can someone explain to me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

One method would be utilize the **Shape Builder** tool and **Pathfinder**..

- Convert the T to outlines via `Type > Convert to Outlines`
- Draw colored rectangles to cover the areas you want colored
- Select All this
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**, hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click the areas you **don't** want to remove them
- Lastly, select all again and click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
  <sup>(This step won't *appear* as though it does much. However, it removes the black areas *behind* the colored areas)</sup>

[image]

Note that my rectangles weren't aligned well to the center stroke of the T. This results in a sliver of color running down the sides of the center strokes. Just be certain to align the rectangles well with the center stroke. I didn't want to zoom in for the animation.

If you wish to do this on *live type*, this *won't* work. But there are other, more complex, methods which will. I can detail those if more information is added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you can't do it, but I guess you might not be aware of difference between text and shapes in Illustrator. With shapes, you have more control and you can *cut* shapes into multiple parts, so you can fill different colors in each of them.

You can easily convert text into outlines (using *Object > Expand* or *Type > Create Outlines* feature) easily and proceed accordingly.

You can also try a gradient fill for a text if you don't want to create outlines and fill color, but that would take some time and result wouldn't be so *perfect*. You'll need to adjust the gradient sliders a lot to give sharp look at *right* places.

Note that once you create text into shapes, you won't be able to edit the *text*, because the text is actually *gone* and what you see is only the shapes. So one should usually outline/expand text once its typeface and weight has been *finalized*.